# Finding specific numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to Java, and have been working on arrays. The task was :

- Print an array of random numbers
- Print the average of said numbers
- Count the amount of numbers within 50 units less/more than the average in the array
- Allow user to enter a number and search the array to see if it's in there

My code so far: (keep in mind, it's pretty rough, I got kinda lost towards the end.) 
All I'm asking is for someone to explain/help with how to find the 50+- average, and searching for user input in the array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] nums = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){

            nums[i] =(int) (Math.random()*1000);    
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){

            if (i % 20 == 0){
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
                System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");        
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){
            sum += nums[i];
        }

        int average;
        average = sum/(nums.length);
        System.out.println("\n\nThe average equals: "+ average);

        int fifty = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){   
            if(nums[i]  <= average - 50 && nums[i] >= average + 50){
                fifty++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Number of values within 50 of the average: " + fifty);

        int usrVal;

        System.out.println("\nEnter a value to test: ");
        usrVal = in.nextInt(); 

    }       
}
```

Comment: dont you want: nums[i] >= average - 50 && nums[i] <= average + 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as you know what your average is

then loop through your array and compare each number to the average

```
  if (Math.abs (nums[i] - average) < 50) {
      System.out.println (nums[i]);
      // or count it or whatever
  }
```

Comment: When I run this, it prints every number in the array less than/more than 50 of the average. To print only the count, how would I go about doing that? I set an int count = i but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @kevin Did you put that counter inside the loop so that it gets reset every time?